# Shortcut for moving a block of code over 4 indents in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, codeblocks

Does anyone know the shortcut for shifting a block of code in IntelliJ over by a few indents?

(For the CSS editor, Coda, I used to select the block or blocks of code and use the shift and left or right carrot symbols to shift the code right or left.)

Comment: Thank you crazyCoder that worked.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

These are common **Indent** and **Unindent** actions, default shortcuts: <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Shift-Tab doesn't move my block of code four spaces to the left. It does nothing.

Comment: Check your keymap and remap if needed.

Comment: It's just that on Netbeans if you have "Hello |World" and you tab it, it becomes "Hello     |World" and then if you Shift-Tab it, you reverse that operation and go back to "Hello |World". Shift-Tab on IntelliJ only works if you indent at the very beginning of the line.

Comment: I had to remove bindings for "Next Parameter" and "Prev/Previous Parameter" for this to mostly work like I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In keymap, find `Unindent line of selection` then right click to add `Shift+Tab` as the shortcut:

[image: Unindent line of selection]